# Rest page counter in PDFTK

Tags: batch-file, pdftk

Long/Short of it is I have a batch file that produces a recon of sorts using GOTO at the end of the batch works as a simple loop to go back to the top of the batch file, wait for user input and process another PDF.

The above logic works great except for one hitch, Using PDFTK to counter the number of pages per file works for the first PDF I run through the process but after I "loop" back to the top to run another it concatenates the last number of pages from the prior PDF file with the current. I only want the current file I'm counting everytime.

See sample code below...

```
pushd %direct%
   for /r %%a in (*.pdf) do (
       copy "%%a" "T:\TEST\GOHERE\SCRIPTS\INPUT\%%~nxa"
   )
popd

for %%a in ("T:\TEST\GOHERE\SCRIPTS\INPUT\*.pdf") do (
   title %%a
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%b in ('pdftk "%%a" dump_data ^| find "NumberOfPages"') do (
      set /a total+=%%b
   )
)
echo TOTAL IMAGES = %total% > "T:\TEST\GOHERE\RECON.TXT"
```

Is it possible to "reset" the counter every time?

Comment: After `popd` insert a line with `set "total=0"` to initialize the variable used to count with value 0.

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks so much!